# How do I get Windows shortcut "Starts In" behaviour when double-clicking on files?

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have a type of data file associated with my program. I can run my program by clicking on a shortcut, or by double-clicking on the data file. Standard Windows stuff.

However, I need to be able to set the Starts In folder to a specific folder. Everything is fine when I use the shortcut (because that has a Starts In parameter), but when I double-click on a data file, the Starts In defaults to the local folder of the data file, which is not what I want.

To be more specific, I'm using a network dongle protection system (Safenet SHK) that requires an XML file to be in the Starts In folder before the protection shell allows my code to be run, so I can't just change the folder in my program, because it hasn't run yet.

What can I do?

Comment: Well, you could have your program change to the directory you want when it starts by getting a file on the command line (which is what happens when it's started by a file being double-clicked in Explorer). If that won't work, you'll need to [edit] your question and be much more specific about what it is that you want to happen.

Comment: Edited for specificity. :) Thanks Ken.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a launcher application.  This application would do nothing but set the working directory and then start the real application and pass in the name of the file the user is trying to open.  Your application shortcut can point to your main application, but the file associations you create would use the launcher.

Comment: Yeah, that was the obvious one but I was looking for a more elegant solution that wouldn't cause confusion for the users (especially with regard to patching the executable)

Comment: If you name your launcher something like `SupportFileProcessor.exe` I don't see how it would confuse the users.  You can also put it in a sub-directory so that users will probably never even see it.

Comment: "I don't see how it would confuse the users" - Famous Last Words :)